# Dynamic row height on Word tables, based on mail-merged contents

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I'm working with Word templates which contain nested tables of mail-merged fields.  I need the row height of one of the child tables to have a minimum height but be able to expand (height only **not** width) to accommodate the contents from the mail-merged data

Anyone know how to achieve this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Using Word 2003, the principle is the same in newer versions, but placement within the UI may vary.*

Select the row in question. Right-click and select `Table Properties`.

From here move to the `Row` tab, and enter a value in `Specify Height`.

Finally, ensure the `Row Height Is` set to **`At least`** and not `Exactly`.

Here's a screenshot of the `Table Properties` window showing the options in question:

[image: Table Properties window showing row height options]

Comment: Works a treat, even if I do feel dumb for not spotting that dropdown option earlier ;-)